# Sorting an ArrayList<String[]> in alphabetical order

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I am relatively new to java and would like to know how to sort an ArrayList of type String[] in alphabetical order. In this case, my ArrayList name is temp. Basically String[] would hold 3 elements: String a, String b and String c. I want to sort the Array List with respect to String a. Im using Java 10.

I have tried this but it does not work

```
ArrayList<String[]> temp = somefunction();
Collections.sort(temp);
```

This is the error which is displayed:

```
sort(java.util.List<T>) in Collections cannot be applied 
      to(java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String[]>)
```

Comment: That doesn't parse for me -- what is the alphabetical order of a list of arrays?

Comment: Why's the address book returns arrays of strings?

Comment: How are you deciding if one `String[]` is greater-than/less-than/equal-to another `String[]`? The first element? All the elements concatenated? Note this doesn't compile because `Collections.sort` requires the element type of the `List` to be `Comparable` which `String[]` is not; you'll need to use [`Collections.sort(List,Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,java.util.Comparator)) and use the appropriate [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Comment: if you're using Java8, this may help `list.sort(String::compareToIgnoreCase);`

Comment: In case it’s not “clicking” in your head yet, you are asking the program to sort a list of string arrays. Not a list of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `Collections.sort` is parametrised by `T` that means the condition `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` should be satisfied. `String[]` doesn't meet the requirement because it doesn't extend `Comparable`.

<strike>`Collections.<String[]>sort(new ArrayList<>());`</strike>
`Collections.<String>sort(new ArrayList<>());`

We utilise `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)` when we want to sort *uncomparable* values.

```
Collections.sort(new ArrayList<>(), (String[] a1, String[] a2) -> 0);
Collections.<String[]>sort(new ArrayList<>(), (a1, a2) -> 0);
```

Of course, you should replace a mock comparator `(String[] a1, String[] a2) -> 0` (which simply treats all elements the same) with the real one.

Comment: And for the OP: note that you will need to defined your own custom `Comparator<String[]>` which determines what your order for `String[]` in the sorted output will be. The examples given don't actually "work", they merely compile. ;)

Comment: Ok that was very helpful thanks, i did something like this `Collections.sort(toBeDisplayed, (String[] a1 , String[] a2) -> a1[0].compareTo(a2[0]) );` but it still shows an error, the entire sentence is grayed out, any ideas why ?

Comment: @RajdeepSinghHundal the comparator you wrote might be replaced with an expression `Comparator.comparing((String[] a) -> a[0])`. That's why the line is grayed out.

Comment: yep thats what it said, what does this mean actually ? any ideas how to get around this or prevent it from replacing my expression?

Comment: @RajdeepSinghHundal the latter is an enhanced version of yours, e.g. it covers the case `a1[0] == null || a2[0] == null` properly. Your version would throw an exception if `a1[0]` is `null`

Comment: @RajdeepSinghHundal, but you can still use the initial version even though it is less reliable

Comment: OMG i assumed it would not compile since it was grayed out but it totally does and it works!! thanks man, appreciate the help

Comment: @RajdeepSinghHundal, grey lines just indicate that there is room for improvement

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are not trying to sort a list of strings (e.g. "cat" is less than "dog").  You are trying to sort a list of arrays of strings.

Is array["cat", "dog"] less than array["dog", "cat"]?  That logic does not exist by default, you would have to define it.

**Example Code**

Here's an example (badly just using the first element):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String[]> s = new ArrayList<>();
    s.add(new String[] {"dog", "cat"});
    s.add(new String[] {"cat", "dog"});
    s.sort((o1, o2) -> {
        //bad example, should check error conditions and compare all elements.
        return o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]);
    });

    //Outputs [cat, dog] then [dog, cat].
    s.forEach(x -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x)));
}
```